# How can I create a php function that will gather all

Tags: php

How can I create a PHP function that will gather all database values and then then return each output as a variable. I have the code to SELECT one value from the database and display it as a variable in PHP. Here is the code:

```
function GetWebsiteName() {
$sql = "SELECT value FROM configuration WHERE name = 'website_name'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['value'];
}

$GetWebsiteName = "GetWebsiteName";
```

Basically I wanted to expand it so that instead of SELECT only one value in this case VALUE I want to SELECT * all values from the database and output them one by one. The issue that I am having is that when calling my return data I am not sure how to code it. I have an example of the SELECT. Here is the code:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`value` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

function GetConfigurationData() {
$sql = "SELECT value FROM configuration";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['website_name'];
echo $row['website_url'];
echo $row['website_email'];
}
```

Does anybody know how to select each one and then output the value using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getConfigurationData($name) {
    $sql = "SELECT `$name` FROM `configuration`";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    return $row[$name];
}
```

Usage:

```
echo getConfigurationData('website_name');
```

Using something like PDO would be better, though.